# How to use a text file to read the select only query which is editable in ADO.Net

Tags: c#, winforms

I just want to ask if it's possible to use an external text file as a query instead of using an embedded resource in a project. I've learned that the embedded resource is a read only property and not possible to edit the content of the file at run time. But what if the compiled code is not running? is it possible to edit the content of the embedded resource? And if that's the case, can it be stored in the BIN folder of the project?

Comment: If you're reading the query from a file, you have to be sure that you trust everyone who can edit that file. If you don't, it's the worst form of SQL injection because the query in the file doesn't need to break out of an existing query using syntax tricks.

Comment: is there something preventing you from using stored procedures?

Comment: A quick solution is to put the Queries in a Table in the Database, that way you can protect them from being edited or tampered. This will avoid SQL Injection and from people reverse engineering the queries from your code

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions. But the thing is, I am pulling the data from a different data source, which is from db2 and then perform ETL to send the processed data to SQL server. The script's value is updated depends on the requirement set by the engineer from time to time.